# Is there an aprx doctor?

Tags: arcgis-pro, aprx

Is there a way to recover a non functioning aprx file?

In ArcMap you could use mxd doctor, but from what I've seen ESRI don't have anything like that for ArcGIS Pro.

Answer (score 2):

There is an existing [ArcGIS Idea titled APRX Doctor](https://community.esri.com/ideas/13424-aprx-doctor):

> It would be great if there were an equivalent to MXD Doctor for ArcGIS Pro projects.

which has been Reviewed but which does not yet appear to be In Development.  I recommend adding your vote to that and, in the meantime, as [@Mapperz commented](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/346188/is-there-an-aprx-doctor#comment565841_346188):

> the dump log is the best bet so far C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\ESRI\ErrorReports

Comment: what program is used to open the dump log?

Comment: @JMVDA I am not aware of one. I think  the value of those dump logs is in submitting them to Esri with as much detail as you can provide about what lead up to them.